# Incorrect mount order with ZFS, encrypted filesystems, and Systemd

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, luks, zfs, cryptsetup

I have a 'bulletproof' install of Arch Linux that is structured like so:

1. `/dev/sda1`: FAT32 EFI partition: mounted as /boot/efi
2. `/dev/sda2`: LUKS encrypted ext4 partition: mounted as /boot (prompt
   password)
3. `/dev/sda3`: Encrypted Swap partition
4. `/dev/sda4`: encrypted zpool containing root filesystem (prompt
   password)

The system boots up and functions but some features are not working properly. At boot systemd complains of a load cycle error, but the real problem is that I have to put in the password to `/dev/sda2` twice (once for GRUB and once for Linux). I used [this guide](https://www.pavelkogan.com/2014/05/23/luks-full-disk-encryption/) to set up a keyfile to unlock `/dev/sda2`, but no dice, it still asks for a password.

This is the hook order in my `mkinitcpio.conf`:

```
base udev autodetect modcont block keyboard zfs encrypt filesystems
```

I tried reversing the order of `zfs` and `encrypt` but that created a different problem where it would not set up my swap partition (it also might have messed up GRUB [I'm assuming it failed to mount /boot?], I had to reboot to the archiso to fix it). It didn't fix my problem anyway, I still had to put in /dev/sda2's password twice.

My `crypttab`:

```
cswap /dev/sda3 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256
```

My kernel parameters in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="zfs=zroot/ROOT/default rw cryptdevice=/dev/sda2:cboot"
```

My `fstab`:

```
# Static information about the filesystems.
# See fstab(5) for details.

# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# /dev/mapper/cboot
/dev/mapper/cboot       /boot           ext4            rw,relatime     0 2

# /dev/sda1
UUID=CE42-9249          /boot/efi       vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=re
mount-ro        0 2

# /dev/mapper/cswap
/dev/mapper/cswap       none            swap            defaults        0 0
```

When booting, the system asks me for the password to `/dev/sda2` before it asks me for `/dev/sda4`'s (even when I swapped the hook order in `mkinitcpio.conf`).

After doing some research, it seems that the problem is that ZFS's systemd target requires the encrypted partitions to be unlocked before it does anything, however I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: You're mixing up device names (`/dev/sda3` encrypted swap vs. `/dev/sdb3` in crypttab). You might end up losing data, see also [Swap encryption#UUID and LABEL](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Swap_encryption#UUID_and_LABEL)

Comment: @frostschutz That is actually a mistake in the post (I did not post this on the computer in question). I copied the crypttab by memory and made a typo. The actual file has the correct path.